# How to insert non-spatial features into a Polygon shapefile - FME 2015

Tags: shapefile, geometry, fme-form

Here is the issue:

- I have the original data (a **shapefile** with spatial a non-spatial features) which I need to transform: (highlighted those non-spatail features)

[image: Original data]

- I need to make some modifications on the data (and for that I'm using **FME Desktop 2015.1**).
- Once performed, I need to write again to a shapefile, trying to keep also those non-spatial features... but NO luck with this structure...

[image: FME]

- Here we can see those highlighted with a feature type: Null. So, once I try to write into a Shapefile, it is just written those spatial ones. But, what I need is also those non-spatial.

------- Edited to add log: -----------------

```
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|WARN  |Polygon feature must have at least 4 coordinates...rejecting 
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|WARN  |REJECTING BELOW FEATURE: 
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Feature Type: `GCCSA_intermediate'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(64 bit real)          : `AREA' has value `0'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(64 bit real)          : `Dwellings' has value `42'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(encoded: windows-1250): `GCC_CODE11' has value `79799'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(encoded: windows-1250): `GCC_NAME11' has value `Migratory - Offshore - Shipping (NT)'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(64 bit real)          : `Per_usu_re' has value `111'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(encoded: windows-1250): `STE_CODE11' has value `7'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(encoded: windows-1250): `STE_NAME11' has value `Northern Territory'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `fme_basename' has value `MB_2011_added_INFO'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `fme_dataset' has value `J:\Analysis\Census\Australia\3_Int\01_MB_with_metadata\MB_2011_added_INFO.shp'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `fme_feature_type' has value `MB_2011_added_INFO'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `fme_geometry' has value `fme_aggregate'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `fme_rejection_code' has value `AREA_REQUIRED'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(entangled: string)    : `fme_type' has value `fme_area'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|          entangled to [SHAPE_GEOMETRY, SHAPE_GEOMETRY]
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Attribute(string)               : `multi_writer_id' has value `0'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Coordinate System: `_LL-GDA94_0'
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Geometry Type: IFMEMultiArea
08 08:21:36|  37.6|  0.0|INFORM|Number of Areas: 0
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a unique ID in your shapefile (not FID) you could add an ID and match the non-spatial ones.

Comment: In your shape file writer, you specify the geometry type. You might need a second writer writing to the same file but with null geometry type. Can't remember exactly what it is called.

Comment: Thanks @Fezter , but it writes only in one format because it rewrites the same file, so it just end with one file type. What I've done is:
- Put a second write with Null type parameter. That (I don't know why) gives me a multipoint shapefile with this non-patial info.
- Then, I put the Polygons and those "multiponts" to be written into a new writer with Polygonz type.
- Finally I get what I needed.

PD: I think I'll need to develop the process for a coming automatization... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, another solution (better than last approach) is to REMOVE any kind of geometry from "those non-spatial" features with **GeometryRemover** transformer.

So, with that, there will be the possibility to write into the shape file Writer properly.

Thanks all for your ideas.